# Calling Function 2nd Time Seems to Not Work

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validate

JS/HTML Section, still skipping section: `$("#NewUserRegistration2").validate();` upon submitting it.

Anyone?

```
            <script type="text/javascript">
            $().ready(function() {
                // validate both Buyer Form and Merchant Form
                $("#NewUserRegistration").validate();
                $("#NewUserRegistration2").validate();

                // Validate "Buyer" Form
                $("#NewUserRegistration").validate({
                    rules: {
                        userName: {
                            required:true,
                            minlength: 3
                        },
                        userPass: {
                            required:true,
                            minlength: 1
                        },
                        userEmail: {
                            required: true,
                            email: true
                        },
                    },
                    messages: {
                        userName: "Required",
                        userPass: "Required",
                        userEmail: "Email@Address.com"
                    }
                });
                // Validate "Merchant" Form
                $("#NewUserRegistration2").validate({
                    rules: {
                        merchUName: {
                            required:true,
                            minlength: 3
                        },
                        merchUPass: {
                            required:true,
                            minlength: 1
                        },
                        merchEmail: {
                            required: true,
                            email: true
                        },
                        merchFirstName: {
                            required:true,
                            minlength: 2
                        },
                        merchLastName: {
                            required:true,
                            minlength: 2
                        },
                        merchBusName: {
                            required:true,
                            minlength: 2
                        },
                        merchAddr: {
                            required:true,
                            minlength: 5
                        },
                        merchCity: {
                            required:true,
                            minlength: 2
                        },
                        merchZip: {
                            required:true,
                            minlength: 5,
                            maxLength: 9
                        },
                        merchPrimPh: {
                            required:true,
                            minlength: 10,
                            maxlength: 11 //Add 1 for 1+XXX
                        },
                        merchTaxID: {
                            required:true,
                            minlength:9
                        },
                        merchPPID: {
                            required: true,
                            minlength:7
                        }
                    },
                    messages: {
                        merchUName: "Required",
                        merchUPass: "Required",
                        merchEmail: "Email@Address.com",
                        merchFirstName: "Required",
                        merchLastName: "Required",
                        merchBusName: "Required",
                        merchAddr: "Required",
                        merchCity: "Required",
                        merchZip: "Required (Format: XXXXX or XXXXXXXXX)",
                        merchPrimPh: "Required",
                        merchTaxID: "Required (Format: XXXXXXXXX)",
                        merchPPID: "Required"
                    }
                });
            });
            </script>
            <h2>Register As:</h2>
            <form action="#" method="post"> 
                    Buyer <input type="radio" name="addType" value="Buyer" />
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;Merchant <input type="radio" name="addType" value="Merchant" />
            </form>
            <div class="buyer"><!--buyer-->
                <form method="post" id="NewUserRegistration" action="../inc/php/v_newBuyer.php">
                    <label>Username:</label> <input id="UserReg" style="width:250px;" type="text" name="userName" class="required" /> <br />
                    <label>Password:</label> <input id="UserReg" style="width:250px;" type="password" name="userPass" class="required" /> <br />
                    <label>Email:</label> <input id="UserReg" style="width:250px;" type="text" name="userEmail" class="required" /> <br />
                    <input type="hidden" name="CurrDtTm" value="<?php $date = date( 'd/m/Y', time());?>"/>
                    <input type="submit" style="width:100px; margin:10px 10px 10px 0px;" id="UserRegSubmit" name="submit" value="Register" />
                </form>
            </div><!--/buyer-->
            <br />
                <div class="merch"><!--merch-->
                <form method="post" id="NewUserRegistration2" action="../inc/php/v_newMerchant.php">
                    <h3 style="margin:2px 0; padding:0;">Account Information</h3>
                        <label>Username:</label> <input id="UserReg" style="width:250px;" type="text" name="merchUName" /> 
                        &nbsp;<label>Password:</label> <input id="UserReg" style="width:250px;"  type="password" name="merchUPass" /> <br />
                        <label>Email:</label> <input id="UserReg" style="width:250px;"  type="text" name="merchEmail" /> <br />
                        <label>First Name:</label> <input id="UserReg" style="width:250px;"  type="text" name="merchFirstName" /> 
                        &nbsp;<label>Last Name:</label> <input id="UserReg" style="width:250px;"  type="text" name="merchLastName" /> 
                    <h3 style="margin:2px 0; padding:0;">Business Information</h3>
                        <label>Business Name:</label> <input id="UserReg" style="width:250px;"  type="text" name="merchBusName" /> 
                        &nbsp;<label>Address:</label> <input id="UserReg" style="width:250px;"  type="text" name="merchAddr" /> <br />
                        <label>City:</label> <input id="UserReg" style="width:250px;"  type="text" name="merchCity" /> 
                        &nbsp;<label>State:</label> 
                    <select class="state" name="merchSt" class="UserReg" style="width:250px;">
                    <?php require_once('../inc/php/states.php'); ?>
                    </select> <br />
                    <label>Zip:</label> <input id="UserReg" style="width:250px;"  type="text" name="merchZip" /> 
                    <!--categories here-->
                    &nbsp;<label>Primary Phone:</label> <input id="UserReg" style="width:250px;" type="text" name="merchPrimPh" /> 
                    <h3 style="margin:2px 0; padding:0;">Payment Information</h3>
                    <label>Tax EIN/ID:</label> <input id="UserReg" style="width:250px;" type="text" name="merchTaxID" /> <br />
                    <label>Paypal Merchant ID:</label> <input id="UserReg" style="width:250px;" type="text" name="merchPPID" /> <br />
                    <!--anon merchant name -->
                    <input type="submit" style="width:100px; margin:10px 10px 10px 0px;" id="UserRegSubmit" name="submit" value="Register" />
                </form> 
                </div><!--/merch-->
```

Comment: Anyone??? I've doubled checked my code.

Comment: can you put up a demo somewhere i can look at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of

```
        $("#NewUserRegistration").validate();
        $("#NewUserRegistration2").validate();
```

just leave the rest of the code

Comment: Yeah, that didn't fix it. I had found that shortly after posting this. See the updated code

Comment: The Edit i just posted should fix it

Comment: anytime :] for future reference when you called those two first they bind the forms without any rules, when you try to bind them again with rules they have already been bound so it basically won't do anything.

Comment: So, they almost just initiate them without rules. Then the next call `$("#NewUserRegistration").validate({});` actually implements the rules?